# Como obter o número de versão do Android?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como faço para conseguir o número de versão do Android no qual meu aplicativo que usa WebView está rodando, para colocar no UserAgent, como no código abaixo:

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; App Mobile Android X.X.X; App v1.0)(KHTML, like Gecko)");
```

Em que **X.X.X** seria a versão do Android.

Comment: Sua pergunta é sobre como _**descobrir**_ a versão do Android?

Comment: Sim e colocar no user agent dentro dessa função ai.

Comment: Sua edição invalidou minha resposta e tornou sua pergunta ainda mais ampla. Reverti para a versão anterior.

Comment: Sua resposta ajudou, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a constante `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`.

Um exemplo de uso para o seu caso seria:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; App Mobile Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "; App v1.0)(KHTML, like Gecko)");
```

Comment: Dei uma atualizada na pergunta, você pode editar a resposta? Peço desculpa não ter sido claro antes.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com marca do celular?

Comment: Queria que descobrisse a marca também e colocar junto, como no exemplo do user agent do Google Crhome, aparece o modelo do celular: **Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; MotoG3 Build/MPI24.65-33.1-2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.68 Mobile Safari/537.36**

Comment: Vou procurar uma solução, mas, se eu encontrar, vou te pedir para criar outra pergunta, já que essa aqui é a única no site sobre esse assunto que tem resposta e pode servir para outras pessoas. Se ficar pouco genérica, é mais difícil de ser encontrada no futuro.

Comment: Muito obrigado!